# Android - broadcast receiver for incoming calls stays alive after unregistering it

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call, block

I have a broadcast receiver for listening to incoming call event. It is defined programmatically not in the manifest. The purpose is to block all calls when that is chosen by the user. But after I unregister the broadcast receiver and close the service that registered it the receiver stays active and still blocks calls. 
what I have tried:

1) I tried implementing this receiver inside another broadcast receiver class I already have in this app and works fine...which means that after unregistering it it stops listening to the other events. And while it stops listening to the other events it keeps listening to incoming call events. (which is just utterly weird)

2) I tried implementing the incoming calls receiver in a seperate broacast receiver class and register it in a seperate service. even after i kill this service it still stays alive.
The calls receiver dies only when the whole app closes.

3)I tried the same thing using an activity instead of a service.

OnDestory is called in the case of service. And the problem persists when using an activity as well.
How is this explained and how can I solve this problem???

this is my code for the seperate broacast receiver class and seperate service implementation:

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallBlockBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    BroadcastReceiver CallBlocker;
     TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
     ITelephony telephonyService;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String number=intent.getExtras().getString("incoming_number");
         Toast.makeText(context, number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         //Java Reflections
         Class c = null;

         try {  c = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());} 
         catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {     e.printStackTrace();    }
         Method m = null;

         try {  m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");} 
         catch (SecurityException e) {      e.printStackTrace();    } 
         catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {  e.printStackTrace();    }

         m.setAccessible(true);

         try {  telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(telephonyManager);} 
         catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
         catch (IllegalAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
         catch (InvocationTargetException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

         telephonyManager.listen(callBlockListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
     PhoneStateListener callBlockListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
         public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){
             if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                     try {
                         telephonyService.endCall();
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }

             }
         }
     };

}
```

ITelephony class:

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;
interface ITelephony {

 boolean endCall();

 void answerRingingCall();

 void silenceRinger();
}
```

my service

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.android.internal.telephony.CallBlockBroadcastReceiver;

public class BroadcastService extends Service{
CallBlockBroadcastReceiver callBlockBroadcastReceiver = new CallBlockBroadcastReceiver();
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getBaseContext().registerReceiver(callBlockBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));


        return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

            getBaseContext().unregisterReceiver(callBlockBroadcastReceiver);


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: onDestroy is called. I checked with Log statements

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that onDestroy() is not getting called in your service. Are there any bindings left to the service? Are you sure you're calling stopService(intent) on the service?

Comment: onDestroy is called. I checked with Log statements

Comment: There are conditions that will get a service started back up. You might add some logging to see if Android is restarting that sticky service.

Comment: I had allready done that. i just didn't include the Log commands in the code i uploaded here. That is not the source of the problem.